# How to start Jenkins job after receive an e-mail

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, exchange-server

I have the interesting task: start an Jenkins job after e-mail notification in Outlook (Microsoft Exchange) was received.

So I imagine workflow like this:

1. Jenkins integrates with Microsoft Exchange server and start listen the mail box for some user (any technic user).
2. After e-mail was received by this user, Jenkins start my job.

Does it possible? Does anyone had such experience?

Answer (score 0):

[Poll Mailbox Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Poll+Mailbox+Trigger+Plugin) should solve your problem.